# How to remove blue dotted suggestion underline in TextView from Apple keyboard dictation?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, voice-recognition

If users use Apple dictation from soft keyboard, after finish their "voice input". It shows a blue dotted suggestion underline for voice correction.

But I cannot get rid of it. It keeps showing on the UITextView, even if I disabled "Correction" "Smart Dashes" and "Spell check" for the UITextView.

What I want is when user click dismiss or close this page, the suggestion checking should finished and no longer showing the blue dots.

[image: Apple dictation]

---

Then I saved the text content and show all data into another UITextView, it still shows up the blue underline. (I'm using attributedText and saved all attributedText as Data into Realm, not textView.text)

[image: Detail page]

Comment: Just a thought, can you strip the styling, pulling out just the text, and reapply the appropriate styling rather than use the attributed text as-is? Or maybe you can remove the underline attributes from the NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Voive Recognition does not know exactly what you said. Therefore it underlines with dotted blue the parts that it may have messed up. This is a system thing and therefore cannot be changed.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I know this is for suggestion. But even I dismissed the keyboard and save all textview's content, then I showed it on another UITextView. It stills shows this blue underline.

Comment: Did you disable spell checking on both text fields?

Comment: Yes, like I said, I disabled "Correction" "Smart Dashes" and "Spell check" for the UITextView.